# Make VBA DateDif behave and round down like Excel DATEDIFF

Tags: vba, excel

```
DateDiff("m", "06/14/1982", "09,01,1982") = 3

A1 = 06/14/1982
A2 = 09/01/1982
=DATEDIF(A1, A2, "m") = 2
```

If I need `DateDiff` to round *down* like `DATEDIF` does, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `Round()`? or `RoundDown()`? Also, is the stuff you formatted as code just worksheet formulas? And you need VBA?

Comment: @BruceWayne What would you round?  `DateDiff` returns a `Long` (probably `Variant/Long`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Evaluate` function in VBA.  However, when working with dates in this manner, you need to ensure that the value being seen by the formula is the number corresponding to the date, and not a VBA Date data type.  If the date is stored in a worksheet cell, you would do something like:

```
Evaluate("DATEDIF(" & [a1].Value2 & "," & [a2].Value2 & ", ""m"")")
```

If the dates are stored as dates in VBA variables, then:

```
Evaluate("DATEDIF(" & CDbl(DT1) & "," & CDbl(DT2) & ", ""m"")")
```

Comment: How did I not know about Evaluate? Works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
  = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(DateDiff("d", a1, a2) / 30, 0)
```

Comment: With `A2:= 9/1/1990`, `DATEDIF►98`, `DateDiff►99`, and your function ► `100`